# TextBox Get clear when div show/hide using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project in which I have two DIVs (DIV1, DIV2), both have no. of text boxes which are creating dynamically.
I have to hide one of the DIV. On another DIV click event I am showing these DIVs accordingly and enter some text in those textboxes of DIV1. When I hide this div1 and show the DIV2 and enter some text in some textboxes of the DIV2 and hide it. When I show the DIV1 the textboxes are empty. I want these textboxes to retain their values that I entered before I hide it. The same occurs with DIV2 as well. 
All these operations are doing by jquery and I need help in jquery.

Can any body help me please.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You'll need to provide your code.

Comment: If you want functionality like tab you go for jquery ui tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code similar as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.container{
border:1px solid gray;
margin:10px;
}
p,input{margin:10px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#p1").click(function(){ $("#div2").toggle();});
    $("#p2").click(function(){ $("#div1").toggle();}); 
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<p id="p1">Text in block2</p>
<div id="div1">
    <input type="text" value="Some text in div 1" class="c1" />
    <input type="text" value="Some text in div 1" class="c1" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<p id="p2">Text in block1</p>
<div id="div2">
  <input type="text" value="Some text in div 2" class="c2" size="20"/>
  <input type="text" value="" class="Some text in div 2" size="20"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Umesh,
I tried your code and it is working fine but in my case all TextBoxes are creating dynamically, these are not present in the inner HTML of the DIV1 and DIV2, 

hence my textboxes are still getting clear.

 $(document).ready(function () {

  $('#MainDiv').click(function () {
 $('#DIV1').toggle();
 $('#DIV2').toggle();
});
});

Comment: @Tanweer, Can you please provide HTML code to show how inputs are created dynamically. So, I can debug and let you know the solution how to go about ?

Comment: Now its solved, actually I did not set the value Property of textboxes when they were creating.

Answer (score 1):

You should be hiding your `div`s by using `.css('display', 'none')`, or by `.toggle()`.

It seems you're deleting them, and then adding new ones to the DOM.

Can you show us your code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I am Hinding my Divs as 
$('#DIV1').hide();
$('#DIV2').show();
and all textboxes are inside these DIVs

Comment: @Tanweer I tried with hide() and show() but it preserves my values in input